# how to get response of get Request on java

Tags: android, http-get

I'm doing an android app, and I just do an get http request and I just wanna knows what I'm doing bad.

this is my request:

```
try {
    String encodedUserNAme = idDispositivo;
    encodedUserNAme =  URLEncoder.encode(encodedUserNAme, "utf-8");
    String url = Constants.URL_OBTENER_GRUPO + "?" + "user="+ idDispositivo;
    Log.w("ObtenerIDGrupo "," url: "+url);



    HttpClient client = Constants.getHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget;
    try {
        httpget = new HttpGet(new URI(url));

        try{
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                    Log.w("ObtenerIDGrupo "," RESPONSEBODY= "+responseBody);
                    idGrupo = responseBody;
                    Log.w("ObtenerIDGrupo "," idGrupo= "+responseBody);

        }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.w("IOException" + e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and this i my response:

[image]

i don't know why the response is like this.
Can someone helpme please?

Thanks

Comment: But what are you trying to get?

Comment: I just want to retreive this:  $rowSelect = mysql_fetch_row($resultSelect);
  if (!empty($rowSelect)) echo $rowSelect[0];

Comment: I can get the response using String.trim(), thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  URL url = new URL(yoururl);
         InputStream input=url.openStream();
         BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(input);
         ByteArrayBuffer baf=new ByteArrayBuffer(1000);
         while((k=bis.read())!=-1)
         {
         baf.append((byte)k);
         }
        String responsedata=new String(baf.toByteArray());
```

Comment: Hey thanks I can get the Response using String.trim(), the resposnse have a whiteSpace and a \n, thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manipulate response like this, try the following code:

```
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();        
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is));

StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    str.append(line + "\n");
}
responseBody = str.toString();
Log.w("ObtenerIDGrupo "," RESPONSEBODY= "+responseBody);
```